# Drone CI - docker plugin - parse error. Why drone can't parse?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, drone.io

could somebody help me, please?
I try to build and publish my image to a private docker registry:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default
steps:
- name: docker  
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    username: ****
    password: ****
    repo: https://*****.com:5000/myfirstimage
    registry: https://*****.com:5000
    tags:
    - latest
```

But got the next error:

```
Error parsing reference: "https://*****.com:5000/myfirstimage:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
15921   time="2020-10-18T17:52:20Z" level=fatal msg="exit status 1"
```

But, when I try to push manually, all is ok.
What am I doing wrong? Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not common to include the *scheme* in the address to docker registry and repo.

Try to write those addresses without `https://` as in

```
repo: <registry-hostname>.com:5000/myrepo/myfirstimage
registry: <registry-hostname>.com:5000
```

Comment: repo should probably contain a slash, so two names after the hostname.